# If multiple hardware not found, delete all values from list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-delete

I am trying to do the following:

If ID is not found inside the array 'hardware', delete all values where ID doesn't exist from the hardware array.

The issue I encountered is that, where I am able to delete one value at a time using the following:

```
foreach ($this->hardware AS $hardware){
   if(!in_array($hardware['ID'],$hardwareList)){  // checks if hardware id is not on the hardware list
     $query = 'DELETE FROM hardware_map WHERE ID='.$hardware['ID'];
     $db->setQuery( $query );
     $result = $db->loadResult();
   }
}
```

It will not remove multiple values, if I delete all of them at once inside the textarea field.

```
<textarea id="hardwareTextArea" name="hardwareTextArea"><?php
  foreach($this->hardware AS $hardware){
    echo $hardware['name']."\n";
?></textarea>
```

Any help is appreciated on how to delete multiple values from the list at once if I delete all the values from the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the IDs that you want to remove them, then use one query by using IN:

```
DELETE FROM hardware_map WHERE ID IN (id1,id2, ...)
```

Comment: How would you find the IDs if you don't know how many IDs are being deleted or what the ID numbers are?

Comment: This is your task to do it, I just helped you about the query.